# How to sort each column by different order?

Tags: java, sorting

I have a 4 column Table and I want to sort each column by rank. I create a Class like below:

```
public static class Fruit {
String name;
int price;
int number;
String location;

public Fruit(String a, int b, int c, String d) {
    name = a;
    price = b;
    number = c;
    location = d;
}}
```

And I want to sort each column by rank, which means that I can firstly sort by name then sort by price in the row of the same name. Also, I want to sort each column not only from small to large, but also sort by reverse order.

I use `Collection.sort(a, new Comparator())` and `Collections.sort(a, Collections.reverseOrder(new Comparator()))` and I use `a.name.compareTo(b.name)` in class `Comparator()`, however, by using `Collection.sort()`, it can only sort all columns by the same order, which means that I cannot sort the first column from small to large then sort the second column from large to small.

Can any one help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

If You want to sort a list of fruits order by name ascending and price descending:

```
    List<Fruit> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // add fruits to list
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Fruit>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Fruit o1, Fruit o2) {
            int r = o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
            if (r != 0) return r;
            return o2.price - o1.price;
        }
    });
```